Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure' to the 'UseSqlServer' call
I was trying to connect mysql server using entity framework. I installed two nuget packages which are Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools. Here it is my connection string in AppSettings.json file:
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "MvcDemoConnectionString" : "server = localhost, 3306; User = root; Password = 123456; database = MVCDemoDb;Trusted_connection = true"
}

and in program.cs file i called that connection string. That code is
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MVCDemoDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration
       .GetConnectionString("MVCDemoConnectionString"), 
    opts => opts.CommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalSeconds)));

But i am getting this error which is

An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure' to the 'UseSqlServer' call.

How can i solve it? Any solution is appreciated.
I tried to execute 2 commands. Those are 1. Add-Migration "Initial Migration" and 2. Update-Database. The first one executed succesfully. But for second command I am getting this error.

That usesqlserver optiin does bot seem right if you use mysql. The error message is for ms sql server, not for mysql.

You're using MySQL, not SQL Server. UseSqlServer tells EF to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to connect to SQL Server. Use the correct provider instead, Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql and .UseMySql. Don't try using Oracle's Connector/.NET, it's full of bugs and badly maintained.

This example shows how to use EnableRetryOnFailure inside UseMySql : UseMySql(con_string,version, mysqlOptions =>{ mysqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(AppConfig.EfRetryOnFailure, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), null);}}));

Also, if you are using MySQL rather than SQL Server you will likely need to also update your connection string, yours looks like an example from SQL Server. If you have MySQL installed then just search for "MySQL EF Connection Strings" for examples on the typical values to connect to a MySQL database. Be sure to remove the EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer package and replace it with the Pomelo MySQL one, then use the UseMySql() as per Panagiotis' comment.

I solved it using MySql.EntityFrameworkCore packages. And Thanks To everyone.
